# Zend Framework 1.12 barcode does not echo into next pages on pdf file

Tags: zend-framework

Barcode does not print into next pages on pdf file. Let me explain. If I want to print 60 barcodes and 15 barcodes on each page. It is printing 15 barcodes, rest of barcodes and pages showing blank. Here is my code

```
public function generatebarcodeAction(){
  $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
        $pdf = new Zend_Pdf(); 

        $hidden =$_POST['hidden']; // i want to barcode of this field.
        // barcode should be print quantity from to quantity to

        $quantityfrom =$_POST['quantity_from']; 
        $quantityto =$_POST['quantity_to']; 
        $rendererOptions = array(
        'topOffset' => 50,
        'leftOffset' => 50
        );
        Zend_Barcode::setBarcodeFont(dirname(ROOT_PATH) .  '/inventory/library/Zend/Barcode/Object/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Semibold.ttf'); 

        $numberOfPages = $quantityto/15;
        $equipmentCount = $quantityto;
for($i = 1; $i <= $numberOfPages; $i++)
{
  $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
  $page->setFont(Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA), 20);
  $pdf->pages[] = $page;
}

foreach($pdf->pages as $id => $page)
{
    if($equipmentCount > 15)
  {
    $barcodesOnThisPage = 15;
    $equipmentCount = $equipmentCount - 15;
  }
  else
  {
    $barcodesOnThisPage = $equipmentCount;
  }

for($i=$quantityfrom;$i<=$quantityto;$i++){
        $barcodeOptions = array('text' => $hidden.$i);
        $rendererOptions = array('topOffset' => 50*$i); 
        $pdfWithBarcode = Zend_Barcode::factory('code39', 'pdf', 
        $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions)->setResource($pdf)->draw(); 
        $pdfWithBarcode->save('testBarcode.pdf'); 

      }
       $quantityfrom = $i;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code you are create 4 blank pages and then draw all barcodes in page number 1. you cant see 45 barcodes because their margin is bigger than page height!!
you may want to add barcodes to `$pages` not to `$pdf`.
be care you should use `for` instead of `foreach` to rewrite `$page`